# Read 72 files at once and grep data from all of them

Tags: r

I need to read 72 files and each file contains student id no and other non-useful information. I only need the student id and put all of them into one data frame

> afile<-list.files(pattern="year")
>
> al<- lapply(afile, readLines)
>
> subtract<-grep('id[0-9]+',al)

but it came out with all data instead of just id no.

data sample:

> "Monthly report"
>
> "University of XXXXX"
>
> "+--------+------+-----+"
>
> "| id   | dep | scores |
>
> "+-------+-----+------+
>
> "| id593 |  2 |  233 |

I need to change it to this:

> id
>
> id522
>
> id533
>
> id544
> which combine all the files' data

Comment: Could you show some example data?  I guess the `student id` is a column in your file and wanted to extract only that column.

Comment: You should use `grep` within `lapply`.  i.e. `lapply(al, function(x) grep('id[0-9]+', al))` to get the index of all those lines that have `student ids`.  Anyway, without any data, it is not easy to say.

Comment: I have just add the sample data =)

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
  library(stringr)
  id <- sapply(al, function(x) {na.omit(str_extract(x, "id[0-9]+"))})
  dat <- data.frame(id, stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 
  dat
  #    id
  #1 id593
  #2 id245
```

#### Update

If you need all the info in that row

```
   dat <-  read.table(text=sapply(al, function(x) 
                   {x1 <- gsub("[[:punct:]]+", "",
                          grep("id[0-9]", x, value=TRUE))
                          gsub("^ +| +$", "", x1)
                         }), sep="",header=FALSE)

   colnames(dat) <- c("id", "dep", "scores")
   dat
   #    id dep scores
   #1 id593   2    233
   #2 id245   2    233
```

I created two files `year1.txt` and `year2.txt`

```
  afile <- list.files(pattern="year")
  afile
  #[1] "year1.txt" "year2.txt"
  al <- lapply(afile, readLines)
```

Comment: my R said I do not have stringr package...besides..just wondering..if I need to showall data from everystudent..like id and the dep...could I use grep ? or I still need to use str_extract?

Comment: @Emilia311 IN that case, you could use `grep`